# IPhone EventKit Discrepancy with NSDate ( Time is off by 1 hour )

Tags: iphone

I was creating an `EKEvent` for iCal but the time was coming out incorrectly.

When I created the `NSDate` and used a dateformatter to read it, the date was as I would expect it.  But, when I would add the date as the `startDate` to the `EkEvent` and would add the event to the calendar it would mysteriously change to 1 hour later.

I checked through the documentation on Timezones and offsets thinking that was the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the iphone settings->Mail, Contacts, and Calendars->TimeZoneSupport, the phone was set to a different timezone specifically for this calendar.